# Using 'D'Alembert's principle' in structural dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I recently enrolled in a structural dynamics course, and am frustratingly trying to grasp the so called 'D'Alembert's principle'. I have probably now checked close to 10 structural dynamics books about the subject, and essentially every single one just states the principle, as 'adding inertia forces', followed by doing examples without any further explanation, such as the example below.

[image]

The equation of motion is established by considering the 'inertial force' through the term $m\ddot u_x $ and 'inertial moment' by $I_G\alpha$ at the center of gravity (dashed lines in the figure to the right).

Moment equilibrium is taken about the bottom hinge to do this, and the book then states that (here) the inertial force gives a contribution $m\ddot u_x\cdot \frac{L}{2}$.

So my questions are;

1. Where can I look to understand this topic better - the books just state how one can perform the calculations, not why. I also don't understand how the derivations such as that in Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_principle, shows why moment of inertia must be included.
2. How does it make any sense to consider the 'moment'/torque from $m\ddot u_x$?
3. Why is the moment of inertia taken about center of gravity in all the examples (I have seen)?

At this point in time - I don't even know where to search for understanding - so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.